# Problem importing a specific library with python 2.7.10

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, makefile

I am trying to install the following package in my MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6:

https://github.com/Michalychforever/CLASS-PT

When i run the make file everything looks to work fine. It not only generate an executable, which i can run by terminal using the ./ command, but also a python wrapper. The problem is related only with the former.

When i try to import the library i get the following message:

```
import classy
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/thiagomergulhao/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/classy.so, 2): Symbol not found: _zdotu_
  Referenced from: /Users/thiagomergulhao/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/classy.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/thiagomergulhao/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/classy.so
```

I am using the built-in python version (i.e 2.7.10). I already installed the Xcode 10.1 together with command line commands. My .bash_profile is:

```
export PATH="/Users/thiagomergulhao/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Does anyone have any ideia what is causing this problem?

Comment: The instructions for the package instruct on setting the correct paths for the shared libraries. Are you sure you have set them correctly? Because the error is related to a shared library file. You haven't mentioned the path that you set and the steps that you took to compile the said library. As per [this](https://github.com/Michalychforever/CLASS-PT/blob/master/instructions.pdf) it is not as simple as `make` to install the library the paths need to be correct.

Comment: @Xk0nSid Thanks for answering! Yes, i followed all the instructions standing there. Actually i have this same program running in my pc with Linux. I've been playing with the makefile, trying to understand what is happening. I realized that it is successfully compiled only when i comment the OpenMP flag. Do you think it is the reason i'm facing this problem? Honestly i have no experience with compilers. The author state that i can comment that flag if i don't need it...

Comment: Solved the problem! The flag -fopenmp was crucial, indeed... After installing python3 (i think this would also work with python 2.7) i searched for ways make this flag work. In order to do that i installed the brew gcc and used in the Makefile gcc-10 instead of gcc. After that everything looks working fine!